# Inverse of a element $A \in \mathbb{F}_{2^m}, A \neq 0$ using Almost Inverse Algorithm

Tags: finite-groups, euclidean-algorithm

I have been proposed in class to obtain the inverse of a given element in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ field with the Almost Inverse Algorithm (AIA).
I do not understand very well how to obtain it since the result that the algorithm returns does not know what has to be applied to have the inverse form.

Let $ \mathbb{F} = \mathbb{Z}_{2}[X]/f(x) $ where $ f (x) = x ^ 4 + x ^ 3 + 1 $ calculate the inverse of $ x ^ 3 + x $
[Almost Inverse Algorithm (AIA)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3reMW.png)

I would like to know if you could help me, showing me the iterations of the algorithm.